# Object-fit: cover not working correctly on Safari

Tags: css, safari, cross-browser

having an issue with browser support right now.

I have it working as hoped for Firefox and Chrome, however on safari I am having issues with images. Currently, the image is set using "object-fit: cover" and has the intended effect on Chrome/firefox. But for safari, it seems to ignore it and the image is very large. 
Here is a screenshot. The left is the intended the right is the actual outcome.
[image]

Here is an html and css snippet of my code effecting this row/column.

```
  <div class="feature-image">
    <img class="img-1" src="@/assets/preview-images/feature 1.png" alt="">
  </div>

  .feature-image {
    width: 50%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
            justify-content: center;
    img {
      width: 100%;
      -o-object-fit: cover;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    .img-2 {
      max-width: 320px;
    }
  }
```

Comment: for me, adding a 1 px black border fixed an issue with `object-fit: cover` not working properly in full-screen mode 

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue. I found that setting a min-height of %
100% instead of a height of 100% solved it in Safari. I haven't tested it on width but it might work for you.

```
.object-fit-cover-photo {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: I had this same issue in Safari. I found setting `min-height: 100vh` worked, whereas `min-height: 100%` did not. But that is probably just for my use case.

Comment: Safari is the new IE

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue and managed to fix it by replacing percentage value of the width (or max-width) property with fixed (rem or px) values. In my case, Safari failed to calculate object-fit correctly when the img element's width was in % or inherited auto values.

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was an `<img>` inside of a `<picture>` tag. And safari was failing to calculate object-fit property.

So as arixtty mentioned - replacing percentage value of the width(for `img`) with "**initial**" value have helped. Or you can use fixed value in your case instead

Answer (score 0):

this has worked for my case on Iphone, I needed the arbitrary image to fill into a round circle.

```css
.parent {
        aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
        border-radius: 50%;
        width: 80%;
        overflow: hidden;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        border: 8px solid var(--col-base-orange);
    }

    .parent img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: none;
        max-height: none;
        min-height: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        flex: 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
 <img src="https://i.imgur.com/j1sDrGv.jpeg" />
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Well The Easiest Workaround is to Simply remove object-fit: cover and add it using scale . Its been tested and it works great

```
.object-fit-cover-photo {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
   /*object-fit: cover;*/
    scale : 1.2; // or whasoever fits best for the device 
}
```

Also add it using media queries to ensure that its added to all standard devices .

That would basically fix this bug .

Comment: This wont cover the same benefits of object-fit:cover though. the scale value would vary depending on the orientation of device, and various other variables effecting the ratio of the container.