# Object-Fit Cover not working on Safari Mobile

Tags: css, cover, object-fit

I've noticed a small problem. The object-fit: cover doesnt seem to work on Safari Mobile. Is there any workaround for it? If u can see in the image, the background image is leaking out of the container. [image]

Below is a snippet of my code:

```
        .background-img{
            width:100%;
            min-height: 100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            z-index:1;
        }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object-fit: cover not working correctly on Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60192601/object-fit-cover-not-working-correctly-on-safari)

Comment: Unfortunately not, I've tried it as well

Comment: Could you put up the code and image that's giving the problem as I haven't reproduced it.

Comment: I've just added my code! It's pretty standard just object-fit: cover but the image is still leaking only on safari mobile.